# Program crashed when loading xml layout

Tags: android

I load a layout xml when the user tap the EditText as follow. But the program always crushes when executing the setContentView(descriptionView); What is the problem?

```
EditText DescEditTxt = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEdit);
    if(DescEditTxt != null)
    {
        DescEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                final View descriptionView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.description, null);
                setContentView(descriptionView);
            }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Then compile code for debug.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crush#Verb vs http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash#Verb

Comment: descriptionView is fine, it is not null. But don't know why setContentView(descriptionView); has problem.

Comment: For starters, you could post the stack trace from logcat, so that we could see what king of an error it is. Second, you could post your R.layout.description layout, because there a good chance the error is somewhere there.

Comment: @CBore serious? yeah error

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing anything, I'm going to guess you can't call "setContentView" on the same activity more than once.  Do a google search.  You'll find that to be a common impression.

Also, read this:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/Window.java#Window.setContentView%28android.view.View%29

"Note that calling this function "locks in" various characteristics of the window that can not, from this point forward, be changed..."

As the man says, you need a new plan, Stan.

Comment: Sorry.  Its "make a new plan, Stan".